# Anyone know how to limit the number of entries displayed between a set of tag pairs embedded in other tag pairs?

Tags: channel-entries, search, embeds

I'm embedding a set of tag pairs with another set of tag pairs, but because there are two entries that meet the criteria of the outer tag pairs, EE's displaying the embedded tag pairs twice.

My code is as follows:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="property_details" dynamic="no" status="open" orderby="random" limit="3" search:featured_property="=y"}
        {if total_results < 3}
            {embed="includes/homepage-properties"}
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

What I'm trying to do is display three 'featured' entries when three or more exist (which is relatively simply using the search parameter in the tag and then an {if total_results > 2} within the tag.

When there aren't three results, I'm trying to just pick three non-featured entries at random as display them. I've embedded a template to enable me to use a tag pair within another, but this is then displaying that embedded template twice as there are two entries that meet the out tags criteria.

Any ideas on how to make it just display the embedded template once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could nest another conditional:

```
{if total_results < 3}
  {if count==total_results}
    {embed="includes/homepage-properties"}
  {/if}
{/if}
```

Comment: That's amazing, thanks Michael! If you've got time, I'd love to understand how that works?

Comment: Sure - the count variable starts at one and increments each time the channel:entries tag loops. When it's equal to the total_results variable it means you are at the last iteration through the loop.

Comment: An alternative approach would be {if count == 1} - then it would only be true the first iteration through the loop.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you and Happy Christmas!